# SQL Query Grabbing All Records Rather Than Last

Tags: sql, max

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
                DOC_LOG
  EXTERNAL_DOC_ID|      TRANS_DATE          | TRANS_IN_OUT | CHANGE_NOTE
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  1234           |  10/25/2020 8:44:50 AM   | OUT          | (MEMO)
  1235           |  10/25/2020 8:46:17 AM   | OUT          | (MEMO)
  1236           |  10/26/2020 9:10:48 AM   | IN           | (MEMO)
  1235           |  10/26/2020 11:06:46 AM  | OUT          | (MEMO)
  1234           |  10/26/2020 11:06:47 AM  | OUT          | (MEMO)
```

Table 2

```
         V_EXTERNAL_DOCS_EX
  ID             |   DATE_LAST_MODIFIED     | FILENAME
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  1234           |  10/26/2020 8:44:50 AM   | K1234-123_SWI
  1235           |  10/27/2020 8:46:17 AM   | AM134568_SWI
  1236           |  10/27/2020 9:10:48 AM   | TCA12345_SWI
  1333           |  10/26/2020 11:06:46 AM  | AUC11345_SWI
  1444           |  10/27/2020 9:06:47 AM   | KMA56780_SWI
```

My first SQL query was this:

```
SELECT V.FILENAME, MAX(L.CHANGE_NOTE)
FROM V_EXTERNAL_DOCS_EX V LEFT OUTER JOIN DOC_LOG L ON V.ID = L.EXTERNAL_DOC_ID
WHERE V.DOC_LIBRARY_ID IN (40,20)
      AND L.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'OUT'
      AND V.DATE_LAST_MODIFIED >= SYSDATE -4
      AND L.CHANGE_NOTE <> 'Document is checked out for changes.'
      AND L.CHANGE_NOTE <> 'New Document is registered.'
GROUP BY V.FILENAME, L.CHANGE_NOTE
```

Results:

```
 FILENAME           |     CHANGE_NOTE
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 RANDOM_FILE        |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
```

Intended results:

```
 FILENAME           |     CHANGE_NOTE
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 RANDOM_FILE        |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
```

2nd SQL query:

```
SELECT V.FILENAME, L.CHANGE_NOTE
FROM V_EXTERNAL_DOCS_EX V LEFT OUTER JOIN DOC_LOG L ON V.ID = L.EXTERNAL_DOC_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(L.TRANS_DATE), TRANS_DATE
                  FROM DOC_LOG L
                  WHERE  L.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'OUT'
                  GROUP BY L.TRANS_DATE) L1 ON L1.TRANS_DATE = L.TRANS_DATE
WHERE V.DOC_LIBRARY_ID IN (40,20)
  AND L.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'OUT'
  AND V.DATE_LAST_MODIFIED >= SYSDATE -5
  AND L.CHANGE_NOTE <> 'Document is checked out for changes.'
  AND L.CHANGE_NOTE <> 'New Document is registered.'
ORDER BY V.FILENAME
```

Results:

```
 FILENAME           |     CHANGE_NOTE
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 RANDOM_FILE        |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
```

Intended results:

```
 FILENAME           |     CHANGE_NOTE
 K1234-123_SWI      |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 AM134568_SWI       |   (MEMO) - FROM 2ND TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
 RANDOM_FILE        |   (MEMO) - FROM 1ST TIME BEING CHECKED OUT
```

I figured using the MAX function would eliminate the pull of the extra row of data. Did I perform the MAX function incorrectly? Any explanation and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to use an analytical `MAX` instead of an aggregate.  This query should do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT v.filename, l.change_note
FROM v_external_docs_ex v
INNER JOIN (SELECT dl.external_doc_id, 
                   dl.trans_date,
                   change_note,
                   MAX(dl.trans_date) OVER (PARTITION BY dl.external_doc_id) AS MAX_TRANS
           FROM doc_log dl
           WHERE dl.trans_in_out = 'OUT') l ON v.id = l.external_doc_id AND l.trans_date = l.max_trans;
```

I also create this db_fiddle so you can try this out ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b04eac3a0a9c4449a38d9d07cf847c50))